# How to compute the operator norm of an integral?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have to compute the operator norm of $T$ of the following integral operator:

$Tf(x) = \int_0^1\frac{f(y)}{1+x^2+y^2}dy$ equipped with the norm $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$

This is what I tried, I was also thinking of using the Holder inequality.

$\Vert Tf(x)\Vert
=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}f(y)\,dy\right|
\leq\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 |\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}||f(y)|\,dy
\leq\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 1\cdot\sup\limits_{y\in[0,1]}|f(y)|\,dy
\\=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 \Vert f(y)\Vert\, dy
=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\Vert f(y)\Vert
=\Vert f(y)\Vert$

Hence, $\|T\| \leq 1$.

I also tried the following:

$\Vert Tf(x)\Vert
=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}f(y)\,dy\right|
\leq\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 \bigl|\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\bigr|\,|f(y)|\,dy
\leq\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 \bigl|\frac{1}{1+y^2}\bigr|\,|f(y)|\,dy$

and then I know that the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+y^2} = \arctan(y)$ combining that with the boundaries, one would get $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Any help would be grateful. I am really struggling finding a correct answer and I am not sure one of the two ways are the right ones. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have already proved that $\|T\|\leq \frac{\pi } 4$. Now obsetve that if $f(x)=1$ for all  $x$ then $\|Tf\| \geq Tf(0)=\int_0^{1} \frac 1 {1+y^{2}} dy=\frac{\pi } 4$. Since $\|f\|=1$ this proves that $\|T\| \geq \frac {\pi } 4$. Hence, $\|T\| = \frac{\pi } 4$.

[$\|T\| \leq 1$ is also correct  but that does not give you the actual value of the norm].

Comment: Is the way how I wrote it correct? Because it seems mathematically incomplete in my opinion and not sure how to improve it

Comment: @Mathlover All you have to do it to pull out the maximum value of $|f(y)|$ (i.e. $\|f\|$) from the integral. Once you do this you will get the upper bound for $\|T\|$ by evaluating the integral of $\frac  1{1+y^{2}}$.